# How to represent Postgresql bool_and and bool_or aggregate functions in JPA 2 using CriteriaQuery?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria-api, criteriaquery

I am trying to write a `Select` statement using `JPA 2` provided `CriteriaQuery` for the following scenario:

1. Group items and if at least one of the columns is 'true', return true
2. Group items and if all columns are 'true', return true

I noticed there is `bool_and` and `bool_or functions` in `PostGreSQl`. Here is a link that explains these functions.
[boolean aggregate functions](http://neovintage.org/2016/05/04/the-bool-aggregate-functions/)
How do I achieve this functionality using `JPA CriteriaQuery/CriteriaBuilder?`

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke any native SQL function using

```
CriteriaBuilder.function('bool_and', Boolean.class, args)
```

Where "args" are the arguments that your function takes, and the second argument is the return type (see the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#function-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-javax.persistence.criteria.Expression...-)). Obviously you then lose database-independence, but then you may not care about such things.

Answer (score 0):

JPA doesn't support custom functions. It's achievable with hibernate ([look here](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-call-custom-function-criteriaquery/)) or with native query. Both will require significant chanegs to your code.

Comment: @DN1 please, post your answer and I'll delete my